# Cómo instalar ggbiplot

Tags: r

He intentado varias cosas y no me resulta. Lo agradecería mucho!

> library(devtools)
>   install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
>   Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
>   from URL https://api.github.com/repos/vqv/ggbiplot/zipball/master
>   Installing ggbiplot
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
>     CMD INSTALL "C:/Users/Gabriela  \
>     Narváez/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9kjR8/devtools195c316c11a7/vqv-ggbiplot-7325e88"  \
>     --library="C:/Users/Gabriela Narváez/Documents/R/win-library/3.5" --install-tests
>
> - installing *source* package 'ggbiplot' ... Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :   cannot open file 'C:/Users/Gabriela
>     Narvaez/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggbiplot/DESCRIPTION': No such
>     file or directory Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
>     no se puede abrir la conexión ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION
>     failed for package 'ggbiplot'
> - removing 'C:/Users/Gabriela Narváez/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggbiplot' In R CMD INSTALL
>     Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Puede que no tengas permiso en esa ruta a la que quiere acceder?

Answer (score 0):

Hay un par de cosas que pueden estar pasando, pero lo más probable es que lo que vez esté causado por tu nombre de usuario:

```
 'C:/Users/Gabriela Narváez/
```

Hay dos caracteristicas que tienden a causar problemas con R

1. Una tilde
2. Un espacio.

Lo mas probable es que si creas un nuevo usuario que se llame, por ejemplo, `gabriela` (sin tildes, sin espacios) y tratas de nuevo que lo logres instalar.